# What is explanation giving by appayya dikshita to Brahma sutra 1:3:38

Tags: commentary, appayya-dikshitar

Can any one explain what appayya dikshita explained about Brahma sutra Shankara bhashya 1:3:38.

Comment: What is the sutra? Add Brahma sutra 1:3:38 in your post.

Comment: I do not know for that only I am asking